# How to I have to understand the Cut in an graph in this case?

Tags: graph-theory

How is $\delta$ defined in (#)?

> Let $G = (V, E)$ be a connected undirected graph and $c : E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a cost function.  Let $T = (V, F)$ be a minimal spanning tree.
> (#) Let $f = \{x, y\} \in F$,
> and let $A$ be the set of all nodes reachable from $x$ in $(V, F \setminus {f})$.
> Then for every edge $e \in \delta(A)$ it holds that $c(e) \leq c(f)$.

Normally the cut $\delta$ is defined like $\delta(A) := \{ e = \{v, w\} \in E 
\mid v \in A \text{ and } w \in V \setminus A \}$.
But then $c(e) \geq c(f)$ is not always true, because you could compare an edge in $T$ with an edge in $T$ and there could be a case like $c(e)$ < $c(f)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition of $\delta(A)$ is correct, and the statement is indeed false (although not for the reason you seem to say: $\delta(A)$ contains no edge of $T$ other than $f$).

The missing condition is that $T$ is a *minimum cost* spanning tree. In that case the statement is true: if there were an edge $e \in \delta(A)$ with $c(e) < c(f)$, then $T - f + e$ would be another spanning tree (this has to be proved but it is not difficult) with smaller total cost than $T$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3966381/whats-wrong-with-my-counterexample-for-an-mst-cut