# Whats wrong with my counterexample for an MST CUT?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, optimization, trees

bevor I start, I want to mention, that there is an quivalent problem here [How to I have to understand the Cut in an graph in this case?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3964094/how-to-i-have-to-understand-the-cut-in-an-graph-in-this-case/3964448#3964448)

But the answer doesn't help me so.

Following Problem:
Given is an Graph $G=(V,E)$, a minimal spanning Tree $G'=(V,E')$ with $k : E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Let $f = \{x, y\} \in E'$ and let $A$ be the set of all nodes reachable from $x$ in $(V, E' \setminus {f})$. Then for every edge $e \in \delta(A)$ ($\delta(A) := \{ e = \{v, w\} \in E \mid v \in A \text{ and } w \in V \setminus A \}$) it holds that $c(e) \geq c(f)$.

Now i  tired to understand this definition, but if I draw it, I get this
[drawed counterexample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HM93W.jpg)

What I am I doing wrong

Comment: The argument is that $T-f+d$ would be another spanning tree (given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3964094/how-to-i-have-to-understand-the-cut-in-an-graph-in-this-case/3964448#3964448)). This argument does not hold in your example, since $d$ is already in $T$. You should revisit the definition of $\delta(A)$

Comment: you should upvote and/or accept good answers to keep the community alive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you write $A = \{6,7\}$, but this is incorrect: the set of all nodes reachable from $x$ includes (trivially) $x$. So in your case $A = \{4,6,7\}$, and then $\delta(A)$ indeed only contains edges with weight at least that of $f$.